# Wrap backbone view events handlers or jQuery event handlers in try catch block

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, error-handling, extend, backbone-views

I want to do global event handling for reporting JavaScript errors. We have minified JS files in production so I'm attempting get it done with the help of sourcemap.

> Unfortunately, uncaught errors (reported by the browser's top-level
>   error handler, window.onerror) do not currently include column numbers
>   in any current browser. The HTML5 Spec has been updated to require
>   this, so this may change in the near future. 
>   Source : https://rollbar.com/docs/guides_sourcemaps/

So now I need to wrap backbone view events in try catch block. There should be generic way of extending Backbone.View. Probably somewhere at `delegateEvents` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how finally I wrapped all jQuery event handlers in try-catch block.

```
// maintain a reference to the existing function
var oldOn = $.fn.on;
// ...before overwriting the jQuery extension point
$.fn.on = function(types, selector, data, fn, /*INTERNAL*/ one) {
  // parameter correction for backward compatibility copied from `on` function of jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.0

  // Types can be a map of types/handlers
  if (typeof types === "object") {
    // ( types-Object, selector, data )
    if (typeof selector !== "string") {
      // ( types-Object, data )
      data = data || selector;
      selector = undefined;
    }
    for (type in types) {
      this.on(type, selector, data, types[type], one);
    }
    return this;
  }

  if (data == null && fn == null) {
    // ( types, fn )
    fn = selector;
    data = selector = undefined;
  } else if (fn == null) {
    if (typeof selector === "string") {
      // ( types, selector, fn )
      fn = data;
      data = undefined;
    } else {
      // ( types, data, fn )
      fn = data;
      data = selector;
      selector = undefined;
    }
  }
  if (fn === false) {
    fn = returnFalse;
  } else if (!fn) {
    return this;
  }
  // ENDS - parameter correction for backward compatibility copied from `on` function of jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.0

  if (fn) {
    var origFn = fn;
    var wrappedFn = function() {
      try {
        origFn.apply(this, arguments);
      } catch (e) {
        //handle the error here.
      }
    };
    fn = wrappedFn;
  }
  return oldOn.apply(this, [types, selector, data, fn, /*INTERNAL*/ one]);
};
```

**UPDATE:**

There was a bug that jQuery-UI droppable divs were sticking to mouse pointer like glue ;) instead of getting dropped and it was traced to this code as culprit.

So please make sure you wrap this extension with condition `if(!(arguments.length === 4 && arguments[1] === null)) {}`

Like this.

```
// maintain a reference to the existing function
var oldOn = $.fn.on;
// ...before overwriting the jQuery extension point
$.fn.on = function(types, selector, data, fn, /*INTERNAL*/ one) {

    // We can ignore .bind() calls - they are passed from jquery-ui or other outdated components
    if(!(arguments.length === 4 && arguments[1] === null)) {
       //rest of the above code here.
    }
}
```